# Extract and replace string from filename in Batch Script

Tags: batch-file

I try to extract the filename from a list of files, replace specific string and feed that into a process. However I got stuck at replace. Any idea?

```
@echo on
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for %%f in (*.txt) do (

            REM echo %%~nf
            set filename=%%~nf
            echo %@filename%
            set Replaced=replaced
            set @ver=!%filename:ToBeReplace=%Replaced%!
            echo %@ver%    
            )
```

The `echo` from `ver` is not what I expected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: I did though. The code is included

Comment: when you are using delyaed expansion you need to use `!` instead of `%` you can combine it with `%` when you are replaceing a string - `set @ver=!filename:ToBeReplace=%Replaced%!` if %replaced% is defined before the brackets block

Comment: It still echoed empty, I still can't figure out what's wrong :/

Comment: What did you expect? What did you get instead?

Comment: Let's say the `%filename%` is `somestring.txt`, I want to replace the `some` with an empty character, result in `ver=string.txt` only. However the `ver` I get is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a file called `something.txt` in the same folder as the following script:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "old=some"
set "new=else"
for %%f in (*.txt) do (

            REM echo %%~nf
            set "filename=%%~nf"
            echo !filename!
            rem set Replaced=replaced
            set "@ver=!filename:%old%=%new%!"
            echo !@ver!    
)
```

the optuput after execution is:

> something
>
> elsething

Comment: Thank you. I realized I should use `!`.